# Filtering on a List of Tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to filter a `list of 2-tuples` where the first tuple value equals `0`:

```
ghci> ys
[(0,55),(1,100)]

ghci> filter (\x -> x.fst == 0) ys
<interactive>:71:27:
    Couldn't match type `(Integer, Integer)' with `b0 -> c0'
    Expected type: [b0 -> c0]
      Actual type: [(Integer, Integer)]
    In the second argument of `filter', namely `ys'
    In the expression: filter (\ x -> x . fst == 0) ys
    In an equation for `it': it = filter (\ x -> x . fst == 0) ys
```

My desired output:

`[(1,100)]`

How can I achieve this? Also, what does the compile-time error mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(.)` is function composition, you want <s>`filter (\x -> fst x == 0) ys`</s>.
Edit: you actually want `filter (\x -> fst x /= 0) ys` because `filter` provides a list of values that *satisfy* the predicate.

The compile time error is complaining because the compiler infers that `x` must be a function because you're composing it with `fst`, but `ys` is not a list of functions.

Comment: BTW, this still doesn't give the output that OP expects.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I just assumed they were using `filter` correctly. I'll fix it.